# how to read the \n in a txt file for using in split

Tags: java, file-io

I have this code here

```
    java.io.File file=new java.io.File("deneme2.txt");
    try{
        Scanner input=new Scanner(file);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String inputFile= input.nextLine();
            String[] sequences =inputFile.split(" ");
```

It reads the file but I have to edit each file since I can not read .txt when the input is like this

```
ATGAGATACG
AGTCTCTAG
```

but I can read when I make

```
ATGAGATACG AGTCTCTAG
```

I tried to make \n and something like that but I couldn't.

So can you guys help me.

AND I know for sure that it has a very simple solution :) a solution that I'm not aware of tho

edit:in first example the 2 sequences are divided with a shift enter but the second one is divided with a single space

Comment: Why do you need to read the next line char when you are already reading line by line?

Comment: Check this example of [how to read a file in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) line by line.

Comment: Can you post a larger snippet of your text file and explain exactly what you wish to do with it.

Comment: in first exampmle the 2 sequences are divided with a shift enter but the second one is divided with a single space.

Comment: Why do you need to split if you only have one word per line? Get rid of the split and see what happens.

Comment: @user2560965 What is a "shift enter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make the code that reads the file independent of the file format.  To some extent, that's not possible.  Any program has to assume *some* kind of pattern to the input -- be it XML, delimited text etc.  So that breaks it up into two approaches:  Either make the file fit the code or make the code fit the file.

From your description, I'm guessing you want to be able to read a sequence of characters that is delimited by whitespace -- **any** whitespace (' ', '\n', '\t'), yes?  If that's true, don't limit yourself to reading by line.  Just read each token.  This, of course, assumes each token is what you want.

I created a test file with the content

```
abcd efg h
ijklm   op  
qrs
```

That has newlines, spaces and tabs.  Then I fed it to the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("testFile.txt"));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            String s = scanner.next();
            list.add(s);
        }
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println(list);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which gives the output

```
[abcd, efg, h, ijklm, op, qrs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you want to create an array of `sequences`? Like you want this file

```
ATGAGATACG       <-- each of these being a sequence
AGTCTCTAG
```

to become an array like this

```
String[] sequences = {"ATGAGATACG", "AGTCTCTAG"};
```

If that's the case, you can just do something like this

```
List<String> sequences = new ArrayList<String>();  <-- create a list
java.io.File file=new java.io.File("deneme2.txt");

try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        sequences.add(input.nextLine().trim());    <-- add to the list each line
    }
```

**Edit**

If its only two lines why not just do this, and forget the loop

```
String s1;
String s2;
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    s1 = input.nextLine().trim();
    s2 = input.nextLine().trim();
} catch(.. ){
}

// do something with s1
// do something with s2
```

Comment: i dont want to use a list for that purpose for reasons that i cant explain here 

But  i think that would be a solution

Comment: Am I right though? You want to create just one array with each line from your file, or do you want to create a whole new array with each line and split them into an array of character? Please explain what you are trying to do with your code.

Comment: yes you are right in some sense.I dont have to create array or something all i want to do is read those 2 strings.Thats it.There wont be any variaty.It will always be 2 strings but in some cases there 50000 per string.To finish all i need is read those 2 strings and use them as string.

Comment: If its only two lines, why not just do something like in my **Edit**

Comment: Because there are files that has 20+ lines full with chara but still just 2 strings seperated by  enter not a space

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense